# JS seconds countup timer to stop with a button click

Tags: javascript, php

I have this timer:

```
var seconds = 0;
var el = document.getElementById('seconds-counter');

function incrementSeconds() {
    seconds += 1;
    el.innerText = "You have been here for " + seconds + " seconds.";
}

var cancel = setInterval(incrementSeconds, 1000);
```

How do I get the timer to stop with a press of a button and turn the number of elapsed seconds into PHP variable  $elapsed_time if possible?
I need this because the PHP code has to calculate this time along with other variables when the form is submitted to the database. If there's some kind of workaround, I'd welcome it.

Comment: Why do you need this in PHP? JavaScript is enough for this

Comment: You can use clearInterval() to stop the interval and then make an AJAX POST call to transmit the value to a server side PHP script. You cannot directly set PHP variables from JavaScript.